# How to completely uninstall Twitter's Fabric SDK from android project?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle, twitter-fabric

I have integrated the Fabric SDK by Twitter to an android project of mine, and now I would like to remove it completely. As I've seen so far, this SDK is fairly new, hence has little documentation and functionality beyond the most common use cases. I haven't found anything related to uninstalling it as yet.

I've tried removing the fabric-related code from the build.gradle file (and of course removing the invocations in java classes), though when I build the project, a file named crashlytics-build.properties appears in the project's folder for a few seconds. My IDE is IntelliJ. I am not experienced with gradle, and know that this wouldn't be more than a superficial method anyway.

So, my question is: how to uninstall fabric completely, without leaving a trace?

Comment: crashlytics is not part of the Twitter Fabric library as far as I know so I don't think this is a problem with that library. Can you post your gradle file?

Comment: Check all your `build.gradle` files (if there is more than one), and look for the `buildscript` closure. In there, you may still have a reference to the build tools that are part of Fabric.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Besides the gradle files, AndroidManifest.xml also contains Fabric related data. Make sure to delete this line from the file:

`<meta-data android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey" android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>`

Besides this, look for `$PROJECT/android/crashlytics.properties` and remove this as well. This file contains the secret API key.

Hope this helps